# Contract two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have two lists of the equal length in the form

`powers=    {{rho th},{mu},{beta},{nu},{r},{}}`

`subscripts={{     }, {a}, {th},  {b}, {r},{mu,al}}`

If there is a repeated element (one in the first list and other one in the second list) which I specify (for example in this case it is `mu`, but not `r`) then I remove it from both lists and create an element with the rest, for example in this case the out put should be

`powers=    {{rho th},{beta},{nu},{r},{    }}`

`subscripts={{     }, {th},  {b}, {r},{a,al}}`

I got the removing part

`DeleteCases[powers,mu,Infinity]`

`DeleteCases[subscripts,mu,Infinity]`

but struggling with the rest.

UPDATE:
I found how to combine the elements, now just need to remove $mu$ from them, but `DeleteCases` does not work.

`posmu1=Position[power,mu][[1,1]]`

`posmu2=Position[subscipts,mu][[1,1]]`

`Flatten[powers[[posmu1]]powers[[posmu2]]]`

It gives `{mu rho th}`, but now I cannot delete `mu` from it using `DeleteCases`.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why are `a` and `al` part of the same sublist in the output?

Comment: Because they stay next to $mu$. That is the point of the contraction.

Comment: I think the problem description could use some clarification ... Why isn't the output `{{     }, {a,al}, {th},  {b}, {r}}`?  What if there's more than one `mu` in both lists?  The clearer the question, the better your chances for an answer.

Comment: I have not used it but there is a tensor package called [xact](http://www.xact.es/)

Comment: I said that mu can only be "one in the first list and other one in the second list"

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're after, at least not without my secret-decoder-ring question analyzer... What's with the {     } list? Is that a formatting issue, or is there supposed to be something there? Or is it simply an empty list. Is {rho th} an single element list of the product of rho and th? Or is a comma missing? *Please* elucidate the goal and provide some concrete examples, illuminated by the steps if needed.

Comment: That is how Mathematica represents covariant and contravariant indices. That missing coma and difference in formatting is a problem for me. An empty list is ok, it means just absence of covariant indices. And the whole problem is contraction of tensor indices. power={mu nu} means g^{mu nu}, subscript={mu nu} means g_{mu nu} and the whole list is contravariant indices of 6 metric tensor, the same about covariant indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it

`posmu1=Position[powers,mu][[1,1]];
posmu2=Position[subscripts,mu][[1,1]];
indpow1=DeleteCases[powers[[posmu1]],mu,Infinity];indpow2=DeleteCases[powers[[posmu2]],mu,Infinity];
If[indpow1!={}&&indpow2!={},powersadd=Join[indpow1 indpow2],powersadd=Join[indpow1,indpow2]];
subscriptsadd=Join[DeleteCases[subscripts[[posmu1]],mu,Infinity],DeleteCases[subscripts[[posmu2]],mu,Infinity]];
powerstmp=Delete[powers,{{posmu1},{posmu2}}];
subscriptstmp=Delete[subscripts,{{posmu1},{posmu2}}];
powersnew=Append[powerstmp,powersadd];
subscriptsnew=Append[subscriptstmp,subscriptsadd];`

I need this additional to save the structure: powers should not contain comma and subscripts should.

Answer (score 0):

This now appears to work

```
c = First@Flatten@subscripts[[Flatten[Take[Position[powers, mu], All, 1]]]];
Delete[subscripts, Flatten[Take[Position[powers, mu], All, 1]]] /. mu -> c
Delete[powers, Flatten[Take[Position[powers, mu], All, 1]]]
```

First, find the item in `subscripts` that corresponds to `mu` in `powers`; call it `c`.  Second, delete that item from `subscripts`.  Third, replace `mu` in `subscripts` by `c`. Finally, delete the item containing `mu` from `powers`.

**Update: cleaner and slightly more general solution**

```
contract[key_, list1_, list2_] := Module[{pos = {Position[list1, key][[1, 1]]}, rep},
  rep = If[Flatten@list2[[pos]] != {}, First@Flatten@list2[[pos]], {}];
  {Delete[list1, pos], Delete[list2, pos] /. key -> rep /. {{}} -> {}} // MatrixForm]
```

Then, for instance,

```
contract[mu, {{mu f}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}} , {{}, {mu}, {beta}, {gamma}, {delta}, {eps}}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \{a\} & \{b\} & \{\text{al}\} & \{d\} & \{e\} \\
 \{\} & \{\text{beta}\} & \{\text{gamma}\} & \{\text{delta}\} & \{\text{eps}\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much, but it does not work for the following 
`powers={{mu},{a},{b},{c},{d},{e}}`
`subscripts={al,mu,beta,gamma,delta,eps}`
It removes two elements in the subscripts. There should be a little modification. Finally it could be `{{mu rho},{}...}` in the power list, which also does not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lack of generality in my solution, which I believe is fixed, at least for the cases given.  Note that there is a minor ambiguity in the question relating to whether deleting `mu` means deleting only `mu` or the entire item in the list that contains `mu`.

Comment: Still there are some cases that do not work. The whole list of possible cases 
`powers={{mu},{a},{b},{c},{d},{e}}` 
`subscripts={{al},{mu},{beta},{gamma},{delta},{eps}}`;

`powers={{mu f},{a},{b},{c},{d},{e}}` 
`subscripts={{},{mu},{beta},{gamma},{delta},{eps}}`;

`powers={{},{a},{b},{c},{d},{e}}` 
`subscripts={{mu f},{mu},{beta},{gamma},{delta},{eps}}`

Comment: @g3n1uss I need clarification in order to proceed.  For instance, do you wish `{mu f}` to transform to `{f}`, `{}`, or disappear entirely?  Also, can I assume that each item in both lists will be a `List` itself (i.e., enclosed in curly brackets).

Comment: each pair of lists should have two elements. In your example the output should be `{{a f},{b},{c},{d},{e}}; {{},{beta},{gamma},{delta},{eps}}`

Comment: @g3n1uss Please edit your question to show precisely what you want.  For instance, if you want just `mu`, and not the quantity containing `mu` deleted, then `{mu}` should become `{}` rather than disappearing entirely in the example in your question.

Comment: the quantity containing `mu` should disappear entirely, but I need to create a list with the rest. For example `powers={mu a},{b}; subscripts={},{mu}`, the output should be `powers={a b}` `subscripts={}`. Or it could be `powers={},{mu};subscripts={mu, a},{c}` the output is `powers={};subscripts={a c}`, finally the last possibility `powers={mu},{a};subscripts={b},{mu}` the output `powers={a};subscripts={b}`.

Comment: Actually I got it. My way is of course not that elegant, but it works.